# net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE at {URL}

Tags: node.js, docker, express, pdf-generation, puppeteer

**i am using puppeteer v1.19.0 in nodejs , is error unreachable after build and run in docker,
is js file**

```
await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--headless'],
      }).then(async (browser) => {
        const url = `${thisUrl}analisa-jabatan/pdf/${_id}`
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
        // await page.evaluate(() => { window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight) })

        await page.setViewport({
          width: 1123,
          height: 794,
        })
        setTimeout(async () => {
          const buffer = await page.pdf({
            path: `uploads/analisa-jabatan.pdf`,
            displayHeaderFooter: true,
            headerTemplate: '',
            footerTemplate: '',
            printBackground: true,
            format: 'A4',
            landscape: true,
            margin: {
              top: 20,
              bottom: 20,
              left: 20,
              right: 20,
            },
          })
          let base64data = buffer.toString('base64')
          await res.status(200).send(base64data)
          // await res.download(process.cwd() + '/uploads/analisa-jabatan.pdf')
          await browser.close()
        }, 2000)
      })
    }
```

and is **dockerfile**

```
FROM aria/alpine-nodejs:3.10
#FROM node:12-alpine
LABEL maintainer="Aria <aryamuktadir22@gmail.com>"

# ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
# NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# SERVER Configuration
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV PORT=3001
ENV SESSION_SECRET=thisissecret

# CORS Configuration
ENV CORS_ORIGIN=http://117.54.250.109:8081
ENV CORS_METHOD=GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,HEAD
ENV CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS=Authorization,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,X-Requested-With
ENV CORS_MAX_AGE=600
ENV CORS_CREDENTIALS=false

# DATABASE Configuration
ENV DB_HOST=anjabdb
ENV DB_PORT=27017
ENV DB_NAME=anjab

    # Tell Puppeteer to skip installing Chrome. We'll be using the installed package.
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true \
    PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/usr/bin/chromium-browser



# SET WORKDIR
WORKDIR /usr/local/app

# INSTALL REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --update --no-cache \
    gcc g++ make autoconf automake pngquant \
    python2 \
    chromium \
    udev \
      nss \
      freetype \
      freetype-dev \
      harfbuzz \
      ca-certificates \
      ttf-freefont ca-certificates \
      nodejs \
      yarn \ 
      libpng libpng-dev lcms2 lcms2-dev 

# COPY SOURCE TO CONTAINER
ADD deploy/etc/ /etc
ADD package.json app.js server.js process.yml ./
ADD lib ./lib
ADD middlewares ./middlewares
ADD models ./models
ADD modules ./modules
ADD uploads ./uploads
ADD assets ./assets
ADD views ./views
COPY keycloak.js.prod ./keycloak.js

# INSTALL NODE DEPENDENCIES
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm -g install pm2 phantomjs html-pdf
RUN yarn && yarn install --production=true && sleep 3 &&\
    yarn cache clean

RUN set -ex \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps ca-certificates openssl \
  && wget -qO- "https://github.com/dustinblackman/phantomized/releases/download/2.1.1/dockerized-phantomjs.tar.gz" | tar xz -C / \
  && npm install -g phantomjs \
  && apk del .build-deps

EXPOSE 3001
```

**And is result**
Error: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE at http://117.54.250.109:8089/analisa-jabatan/pdf/5ee9e6a15ff81d00c7c3a614
at navigate (/usr/local/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:120:37)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
-- ASYNC --
at Frame. (/usr/local/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
at Page.goto (/usr/local/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:674:49)
at Page. (/usr/local/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
at puppeteer.launch.then (/usr/local/app/modules/analisajabatan/methods/pdfpuppeteer.js:60:20)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Answer (score 0):

From the puppeteer docs:

*****page.goto will not throw an error when any valid HTTP status code is returned by the remote server, including 404 "Not Found" and 500 "Internal Server Error"*****

so providing the url is valid, the server doesn't seem to be sending a response.